# SQL: How do I sort on an alias calculated column ADD add a count?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL and having difficulty getting information out of my database, perhaps someone can provide guidance.  I have

Table: students

Columns:

```
name, notes, test_1_score, test_2_score, test_3_score, test_4_score, test_5_score,
test_6_score, test_7_score, test_8_score, test_9_score, test_10_score
```

I can get the below code to run without the points_achieved in the GROUP BY but that is what I want to sort on.  Also, I could not get the calculation to work without the IsNull added.

```
SELECT
name, 
notes, 
SUM (IsNull (test_1_score, 0) + IsNull (test_2_score, 0) + IsNull (test_3_score, 0) + IsNull (test_4_score, 0) + IsNull (test_5_score, 0) +IsNull ( test_6_score, 0) + IsNull (test_7_score, 0) + IsNull (test_8_score, 0) + IsNull (test_9_score, 0) + IsNull (test_10_score, 0)) AS points_acheived
FROM students
GROUP BY
points_achieved, name, notes;
```

Ultimately, I would like a simple answer to show:
name   points_achieved  (add a count of # tests completed)…….notes

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The model is not ideal, you should at least have one students table, and one tests table, with columns (student_id, test_id, score).

Comment: i agree with @X.L.Ant : you should rather create those tables, since the number of tests can change. You don't want to add a column each time you create a new test

Comment: this way it will be easier for you to work with the data

Comment: Don't include `points_achieved` in your `GROUP BY` clause; that's your aggregate column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
name, 
notes, 
SUM (IsNull (test_1_score, 0) + IsNull (test_2_score, 0) + IsNull (test_3_score, 0) + IsNull (test_4_score, 0) + IsNull (test_5_score, 0) +IsNull ( test_6_score, 0) + IsNull (test_7_score, 0) + IsNull (test_8_score, 0) + IsNull (test_9_score, 0) + IsNull (test_10_score, 0)) AS points_acheived
FROM students
GROUP BY
points_achieved, name, notes
order by 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the fact that various boolean operators in SQL have the value 1 or 0 for true or false.

So the expression `test_1_score IS NOT NULL` will have the value `1` if that column has a valid value.

Use this query:

```
SELECT name, notes,
       SUM(IsNull(test_1_score,0) + /* etc */) AS points_achieved
       SUM((test_1_score IS NOT NULL) + (test_2_score IS NOT NULL) + /*etc*/) AS tests_taken
  FROM students
 GROUP BY name, notes
```